# Issue for "Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters."

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying tutorial for Angular 12 from https://www.positronx.io/build-angular-crud-application-with-nodejs-and-express-rest-api/ and cannot execute below command:

```
npm install express cors body-parser mongoose
```

Below is the code:

```
PS D:\VArdhan\projects\node-angular\test> npm init

This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.

package name: (test) npm install express cors body-parser mongoose

Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

Comment: `package name` was expecting the name you want to use for _your_ package, not a list of dependencies you want to install. `npm install ...` is the command to run _after_ you've successfully created a package to install those dependencies in.

Comment: It's asking for a name and you're giving it an npm command.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a request for confirmation. The failure you're seeing could be solved by pressing **return/enter** and confirming the name. After doing this you will see multiple details to be confirmed. (test) is indeed a url-friendly name.